# Why is a table not using the body font size even though I haven't set the table font size explicitly?

Tags: html, css, html-table, font-size

I have a problem whereby I have set the body font-size to 11px, but tables display font at 16px. I have no idea whats causing this - I have been over the CSS and the output (source when browsing to the page) time and time again. Setting table font-size to 11px explicitly has the desired effect, but I shouldn't need to set it anywhere apart from the body style.

I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #E7D2B8;
    color: #863F2B;
}
img.headerImg {
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-strip {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
.main-content {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
ul.menu {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div.footer {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
ul.footer-links {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.footer-links li {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul.footer-links li:last {
    clear: right;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

...and the output is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CustomerApp_v2/CSS/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img class="headerImg" alt="Header image" src="/CustomerApp_v2/Images/header.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="menu-strip">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Contacts
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li>Customers</li>
                        <li><a href="/CustomerApp_v2/Agents/Agents.php">Agents</a></li>
                        <li>Artists</li>
                        <li>Suppliers</li>
                        <li>Other</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Code</td>
                        <td>Forename</td>
                        <td>Surname</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>Postcode</td>
                        <td>Telephone</td>
                        <td>Fax</td>
                        <td>Edit</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='7'></td>
                        <td><a href='/CustomerApp_v2/Agents/Edit.php'>Create</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>code4</td>
                        <td>James</td>
                        <td>Blue</td>
                        <td>address11<br />address24<br />address32<br />town5<br /></td>
                        <td>postcode4</td>
                        <td>fone4</td>
                        <td>fone2</td>
                        <td><a href='/CustomerApp_v2/Agents/Edit.php?ID=2'>Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>code5</td>
                        <td>Fred</td>
                        <td>White</td>
                        <td>address13<br />address24<br />address31<br />town1<br /></td>
                        <td>postcode2</td>
                        <td>fone5</td>
                        <td>fone3</td>
                        <td><a href='/CustomerApp_v2/Agents/Edit.php?ID=1'>Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <ul class="footer-links">
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
                <li>Link 4</li>
                <li>Link 5</li>
                <li>Link 6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I seriously cant see anything which could set the font-size to 16px in the table. This happens for all 3 sections (thead, tfoot, tbody). It also seems that Netbeans 6.9 will not format the table properly, but it does the rest of the document (before and after). Its almost as if there is something wrong with the table, but I can't see what. This happens in Firefox and Opera (most recent versions of both). I haven't tested it in IE because it will never be used in IE.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Are the browsers rendering in quirks mode? Apparently quirks mode recreates some legacy behavior where tables do not inherit properly:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120718183019/http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2002/table-inherit/

Comment: They shouldnt be - to put a browser in quirks mode you have to do it yourself, right? If thats the case then no, they arent..

One thing I did just think of - could it be to do with the doctype? Only I have used Netbeans 6.9 for all these pages, and it has never happened in any page before now. I am wondering if it is to do with the declaration set by Netbeans when creating the file..

Comment: I was right - I changed transitional to strict and it worked fine!

Comment: The DOCTYPE and quirks mode are inextricably linked - if you're not using a valid DOCTYPE, your browser will be rendering in quirks mode and, in FF's case, at least, using the 'quirks' stylesheet which includes styles very similar to those you are describing.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Using the correct DOCTYPE to avoid triggering quirks mode will avoid the problem. You'll find a description of what's going on in quirks mode with the table cell font-size inheritance at the bottom of http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html (the "font sizes of table cells" section.)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. will make sure I save it in case I have more problems in the future.

Comment: @grossvogel The link you had in your answer was no longer working.  I've replaced it with a version from the internet archive but it would be great if you could include some context from the link here in the event the link is not working.

Comment: I am having the same problem with my tables. My header is set to <!DOCTYPE html> according to HTML5 and I tried the transitional and strict, both did not work. I also tried applying CSS font-size inherit to the table and that also did not work. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Just one important thing, If you add, for example, var_dump before DOCTYPE then your browser might/will go into quricks also. DOCTYPE must be at beginning of document.

Answer (score 35):

Ever wonder why an `<h1>` looks BIG even when you don't use any CSS rules?

This is because web browsers have default CSS rules built in. Included in this default CSS are rules for tables.

Unfortunately, these hidden CSS rules sometimes play nasty tricks on us web developers, and this is why people use [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

So, somewhere under the hood, FireFox has decided that there is an additional rule...

```
table {
    font-size:16px; /* actually it's "-moz-initial"
                       you can check this using FireBug
                     */
}
```

Then your rule is...

```
body {
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Both these rules have a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of 1, so the browser gets to decide a little arbitrarily which takes precedence.

So, to fix this, either target the table yourself:

```
table {
    font-size:11px;
}
```

... Or increase the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of your rule.

```
html body { /* increased specificity! */
    font-size:11px;
}
```

... Or use a [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: It should be mentioned, that resetting also helps to develop pages with good browser-compability. I also reset margins and paddings to achieve a layout that looks almost identical within several browsers.

Comment: I will try using this at some point in the future. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Incidentally, you can check the browser stylesheets in Firefox using URLs like `resource://gre/res/html.css`

In this case, though, they show you that Firefox doesn't actually have a rule to set the font-size of table cells different from the body.

If you look at the Quirks Mode CSS, though: `resource://gre/res/quirk.css` you'll find that in quirks mode, it sets table font-size to the browser default (`font-size: -moz-initial;`)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the **DOCTYPE** set correctly (W3C will have details) ...

OR

```css
table {
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

And all will be well ;)

Answer (score 5):

Don't know what the reason for this is, but since my beginning with CSS & HTML 8 years ago, this was always the case, that tables don't inherit the font-size from the body. Same goes for select- and input-elements.

So I always do something like:

```
body, table, select, input {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

So this is kind of a workaround, that works for me.

Comment: This is probably the case for IE (lets face it - IE is the most likely culprit of such a stupid glitch..!). Failing that, if you have the doctype set to transitional try setting it to strict and see if it solved the problem. I dunno what the actual differences are, but this worked for me anyhow.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: You might find it easier to use `table, caption { font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; }`

Answer (score 2):

I just found out what the answer is - it was the doctype. I think Dreamweaver, Visual Studio and Eclipse PHP all create the files with doctype set to strict, whereas netbeans sets it to transitional. Change transitional to strict and the inheritance from body to tables works fine.

Thanks for the help anyway everyone.

Regards,

Richard