# Why does Chrome/WebKit override a body CSS declaration in a table element?

Tags: html, css, webkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS - table not using body font size even though I havent set the table font size explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388705/css-table-not-using-body-font-size-even-though-i-havent-set-the-table-font-size)

CSS declaration: `body { font-size: .75em; }`

HTML:

```
<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</d>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Helllo.</p>

</body>
```

In WebKit (Chrome, Safari) there's a user agent CSS override for the `table` element of `font-size: medium` which makes the table bigger. I think this is obnoxious and OK I can just write the CSS declaration like `body, table { font-size: .75em; }` but I'm hoping someone can 'splain the logic of it.

Thanks.

**Update** eh, I guess it was a `DOCTYPE`-less quirks mode thing but still, that's obnoxious, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in Chrome for a minimum font size...could that be anything to do with it? See this [long discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=389f306a52817110&hl=en) on the subject.